# Как собрать Qt проект под другую машину?

Tags: qt, qt5

Собираю бинарь на своей машине, загружаю на сервер(другая машина), не запускается. Заявляет мне :

```
/usr/local/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found
```

Говорю ему:

```
qmake -v
```

`qmake version 3.1` у обеих машин, а вот что касается Qt version - версии разнятся.

Там qt5.12 у меня 5.15, хотя устанавливал одинаково через apt - неясно как так вышло, но как-то вышло.
install, update, upgrade пробовал
В интернете нашел, что все используют тулзу MaintenanceTool и она должна быть в корне qt, но у меня её в /usr/bin/x86-64-linux-gnu/qt... её нет нигде.

Казалось бы, тривиальная тема, но чего-то я уже зарылся, может есть какой-то нормальный, автоматизированный путь?
linux
сервер ubuntu 20.04 lts
моя машина ubuntu 22.04 lts

Вероятно поможет собрать на моей машине под другой Qt, но я пока что только разбираюсь с этим.Да и это такое себе решение

Comment: всё правильно в разных версиях убунты, в репозитариях разные версии Qt, а в 18-й Qt5.9

Comment: поставьте себе Qt5.12, для этого скачайте online installer и запускайте без sudo, тогда Qt установится у вас в домашнем каталоге

Comment: но скорее всего программа собраная в 22 не заработает на 20 из-за другой версии glibc, но наоборот будет работать

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, насколько я знаю, онлайн установщик не работает сейчас. Либо оффлайн, либо собирать из исходников.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ такой:
Собирайте исходники на тех версиях, на которых вы собираетесь запускаться.(В крайнем случае собирайте на более старой версии). Это один из самых простых и верных способов(Но он не единственный).

Я сделал такие действия :

- использовал утилиту python [qmake2cmake](https://www.qt.io/blog/introducing-qmake2cmake):

```
python -m pip install qmake2cmake
qmake2cmake_all ~/projects/myapp --min-qt-version 3.1
```

- Если у вас ругается на `DISTFILES` просто закомментите их на время и запустите заново.
- После этого вы получаете CMake файл.
- Дело за малым - исходники перенесите на нужную машину, создавайте папку bin в исходниках, в ней `cmake ../`, потом make(тоже в папке bin, но если ругается на пути разныето можно и в папке с исходниками, просто там немного захламиться файлами)
- Конкретно у меня возникла проблема с `qt_add_executable` , замените просто на `add_executable` и перезапустите cmake и make.
- Готово, в директории, в которой вы запускали make и лежит ваш собранный проект. Не забудьте удалить исходники!